# Как можно обратиться к каждому элементу по ключу объекта в массиве ( js)?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как обратиться к каждому элементу объекта с ключом `firstname` (Например ('Jan'))?

```
const people = [
 { id: 118, firstName: 'Jan', lastName: 'Rycke' },
 { id: 101, firstName: 'Lee', lastName: 'Haverbeke' },
 { id: 114, firstName: 'Clara', lastName: 'Aernoudts' },
 { id: 201, firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'Bernardus' },
];
```

Comment: peaple.forEach((item) => { console.log(item.firstName) )

Comment: Либо отфильтровать нужные элементы: `people.filter(person => person.firstName === 'Jan')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let user = people.find(el => el.firstName === 'Jan');
console.log(user);
```

Если просто к каждому элементу, то через цикл, например

```
peaple.forEach(item => { 
    console.log(item.firstName);
});
```