# Функция getPersonIndex

Tags: javascript

Напиши функцию `getPersonIndex`, которая принимает массив people и последнюю букву имени `nameEndsWith` и возвращает индекс первого подходящего человека или `null`, если никого не нашли. Советуем воспользоваться методом `findIndex`.

Пример:

```
const people = [
 { id: 118, firstName: 'Jan', lastName: 'Rycke' },
 { id: 101, firstName: 'Lee', lastName: 'Haverbeke' },
 { id: 114, firstName: 'Clara', lastName: 'Aernoudts' },
 { id: 201, firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'Bernardus' },
];

getPersonIndex(people, 'a') === 2
getPersonIndex(people, 'k') === null
```

Comment: Вы всесте учитесь? [Вопрос был задан недавно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452646/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-js)

Answer (score -1):

Должно помочь:

```
const getPersonIndex = (people, nameEndsWith) => {
    const index = people.findIndex((item) => (
        item.firstName.lastIndexOf(nameEndsWith) === item.firstName.length - 1
    ));

    return index === -1 ? null : index;
}
```

В данном случае нам нужно вспомнить несколько методов массива:

```
findIndex()
```

и

```
lastIndexOf()
```

Первый принимает колбек-функцию, которая вызывается для каждого элемента массива до того момента пока не вернет `true`. В качестве возвращаемого значения метод `findIndex` вернет индекс найденного элемента.

Метод `lastIndexOf` работает по схожему принципу, но совершает перебор с конца массива

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а чем его можно дополнить? вопрос был "напишите", я написал. или вы имеете ввиду объяснение работы функции?

Comment: 1. вообще на вопросы типа «напишите мне то-то и то-то» лучше не отвечать вовсе. они в подавляющем большинстве бесполезны для базы знаний и потому закрываются и удаляются. 2. но если решили «спасти» подобный вопрос, то имеет смысл описать — что именно вы предлагате. в таком виде ответ (и, собственно, вопрос) могут стать полезными. ориентируйтесь на [хорошие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa).

Comment: спасибо за совет